# Obj-C: FSEvent Reports the Same Event Upon Each Launch of the App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fsevents

I setup a FSEvent that runs well but it keeps reporting the same event each time I launch the app.

Ex:

My FSEvent monitor directory is:

```
Test/
```

...and there are three files:

```
test1, test2, test3
```

However, after I deleted `test1` in my FSEvent Directory, it keeps telling me that `test1` has been deleted every time I run the program instead of just the one time after the deletion.

I cleaned all managedObjects in my context and deleted the whole directory but the event keeps being reported.

What should I do such that it only tells me right after the deletion and then never again?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show some code for how you set up the event stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File system event are persistent between launches. They are tracked by the file system itself, not the app. That is why you keep seeing the event every time you launch.

<strike>I believe you have to call `FSEventsPurgeEventsForDeviceUpToEventId` or the like to clear the events.</strike>

Take that with a grain of salt. I haven't fiddled with it much.

### Edit:

From [File System Events Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-DontLinkElementID_12):

> To work with persistent events, your
>   application should regularly store the
>   last event ID that it processes. Then,
>   when it needs to go back and see what
>   files have changed, it only needs to
>   look at events that occurred after the
>   last known event. To obtain all events
>   since a particular event in the past,
>   you pass the event ID in the sinceWhen
>   argument to FSEventStreamCreate or
>   FSEventStreamCreateRelativeToDevice.]
>   [On a per-device basis, you can also
>   easily use a timestamp to determine
>   which events to include. To do this,
>   you must first call
>   FSEventsGetLastEventIdForDeviceBeforeTime
>   to obtain the last event ID sinceWhen
>   argument to
>   FSEventStreamCreateRelativeToDevice.

I think the important thing to remember is that the file system events are not actually stored or even related to app that is observing them. They exist independently of the app in the file system itself. In practice, several different apps could be set to observe the same event.

Comment: The docs for `FSEventsPurgeEventsForDeviceUpToEventId` say "Can only be called by the root user".

Comment: Yes, I was misremembering. See my edit for the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am really a newbie.. Q_Q

Comment: Or pass kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow to only consume events from when you set up your stream.